# No sound from Firefox or Chrome HTML5 videos, but flash works (alsa)

Tags: firefox, alsa, chrome, hdmi

I am posting this question up mostly because after years (yes, years - cf. [this post][1], for example) of living with this frustration, I finally solved this yesterday and would like to spare others this frustration.

I mainly use `Firefox` for my browsing needs, but at some point I ran into not being able to watch videos on twitter and found that `Chrome` could play them, except that I couldn't hear anything. Some investigation showed that it was due to the fact that these were `HTML5` videos, and neither Firefox nor Chrome would produce sound on HTML5 videos (as tested on Youtube, for example) while flash on both worked fine.

If you ran into the same problem and solved this some other way, please post your solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further investigation led me to find that if I launched `pulseaudio` before launching Chrome, I could get sound coming out of my TV via the `HDMI` connection. Strange.

No amount of tweaking the `.asoundrc` fixed this issue, where I had previously added:

```
defaults.pcm.card 0
defaults.ctl.card 0
```

To fix the problem, but this was obviously no longer working.

Then I found this file: `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.d/99-pulseaudio-default.conf`:

```
# Default to PulseAudio

pcm.!default {
    type pulse
    hint {
        show on
        description "Default ALSA Output (currently PulseAudio Sound Server)"
    }
}

ctl.!default {
    type pulse
}
```

Which looked very suspicious, so I commented out all the lines (deleting would achieve the same effect). Restarted my browers, and *poof* now I have sound in HTML5 videos. It is strange, because you would think that alsa would take my `.asoundrc` with greatest priority, where I specify my `!default` to be something else (ie, not pulseaudio). But there you have it. Problem solved. Hope this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I am adding as a separate answer since this is a separate approach, and people will vote according to the one that solves their specific case (also I am curious to see which solution solves the problem for the greatest amount of people.)*

I just ran into another problem trying to get Chrome to use `JACK` in order to get dmix-like behavior (ie, multiple processes sharing the soundcard). If you use `qjackctl` (or some other such JACK manager) and you are not getting sound when you used to, or know you should be, you might have renamed the JACK server to something other than "default" (or whatever Chrome might be expecting).

To solve: go to qjackctl, click on "setup" and where it says "Parameters" there is a dropdown for "Name", select "(default)" (or whatever name you think Chrome is expecting), restart Chrome and done.